# C#: ObjectDisposedException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, interface, browser

I have a secret project I am working on and basically what it does is go to a page using the web browser fills out the form then clicks submit.

Yesterday everything was working OK but today my interface keeps lagging everytime the code to fill out data to forms on the site starts.

In the C# IDE this is the error I am getting:

> C#: ObjectDisposedException was unhandled by user code

...and when I view the details of it I get:

> The name '$exception' does not exist in the current context

Anybody have any idea of what I have to do? Do I have to dispose something or...?

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us the problematic code. And the problem is not that you have to dispose something, but that you disposed something and are using it afterwards anyway.

Comment: Also, you probably mean `ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: @svick `ObjectExposedException` sounds much more fun ;)

Comment: Alright the interface lags when it goes to the site and attempts to fill to it. The code to visit the site is the usual webbrowser.navigate and this is where the error starts: webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("oauth_signup_client_fullname").SetAttribute("value", txtBoxImportNames1.Text + txtBoxImportNames2.Text);
                    ....then sometimes when I wait for the lag to subside a bit the next error of the same kind is here:  pictureBox1.Load(bob.GetAttribute("src"));

Comment: I edited the code to ObjectDisposedException, whoops :)

Comment: I read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124833/is-it-possible-to-test-if-a-webbrowser-document-has-been-disposed-so-that-i-don and it might have to do because I am using the DocumentText with my webbrowser but still why am I getting the error?

Comment: My psychic powers don't work on Fridays but if I have to guess, I'd say that it's caused by aliens. Seriously though, we really can't help if you don't show us the code that's throwing the exception.

Comment: I did, read the above comments. The error happens when it begins to fill out the form then it lags like crazy

Comment: @user1017524, I would suggest that you put your code samples directly in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that

```
webBrowser1
```

is of type

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
```

then the error simply means that you already disposed the webBrowser1 object, prior to calling the rest of your code.  So the fix is to simply make sure you dispose of the object at the appropriate time.

Declaring your webBrowser1 object inside of a using block will make the scope more explicit, e.g.

```
using(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser())
{

    //put calls to your functionality here e.g.
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("oauth_signup_client_fullname")
       .SetAttribute("‌​value", txtBoxImportNames1.Text + txtBoxImportNames2.Text);

    //or pass it to another function, and it will still get disposed correctly, e.g.
    myOtherFunctionality(webBrowser1);

}
```

will help ensure that you both dispose of the WebBrowser object appropriately (since it is resource intensive) and that you only use it while it is active (since it is only accessible within the using block).

[The using block also helps ensure proper disposal even when an exception occurs.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: Hey from what I saw the code is working but now I am getting an annoying:Object reference not set to an instance of an object. after I implemented it. I have no clue why I am getting it because I am getting the error on a seperate if statement that upon a complete different part of the site I am working with...

Comment: And when I try to add it specifically for the if/then statement where the interface began to lag I get this error: A local variable named 'webBrowser1' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'webBrowser1', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: And also this:'webBrowser1' conflicts with the declaration